# Como generar campo para formato de tarjeta bancaria

Tags: javascript, html5

Buen día.
Requiero generar un formato de para tarjeta bancaria que separe números en grupos de cuatro al irse escribiendo.
Ejemplo: 0124-5424-2264-5585
De antemano, gracias.

Comment: Por favor lee [ask], recomiendo para evitar cierren tu pregunta que ya lleva dos votos muestres lo que llevas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

podrias buscar codigo ya listo o podrias simplemente concatenarle un - dependiendo la longitud. Por ejemplo:

Primero debes tener el input en el html

```
<input type="text" id="numberCreditCard" onchange="myFunction()">
```

Luego debes tener la funcion en el script:

```
myFunction(){
     let numberCredit = document.getElementById("numberCreditCard").value;
     //Aca obtenes el valor de la tarjeta
     if(numberCreditCard.length == 4 || numberCreditCard.length == 8 ||
         numberCreditCard.length == 12){
       //Podrias hacer algo asi
       numberCredito += '-';
      //Aca le concatenas el -
     }

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

utiliza una expresión regular ahí puedes indicar que te acepte 4 dígitos consecutivos, (4 4 4 4) y o cuatro dígitos separados por un guion ( 4-4-4-4) si así lo requieres.   Te dejo un ejemplo de una expresión regular que acepta la lectura de código de barras  su captura desde teclado , esta expresión solo permite la lectura desde la pistola y la captura desde el teclad en el formato indicado y solo la cantidad de dígitos que ahí se expresa.

`var expreg =/^[0]{4}[0-9]{8}[0-9]{4}$/;`

te proporciono un enlace donde puedes formular las expresiones y hacer un test en tiempo real [regular expresion](https://regex101.com/)

Espero te sea de utilidad

Saludos